# javascript: How to assign a function to an element

Tags: javascript, jsp

Here's what I want:

I have an  element in my html code, and I want to assign a function to the onClick event, depending on some conditions to be known down the road.

For example

```
<a href="" id = "element"><img .....>

//other code

</a>
```

Then I want to do something like this

```
 <logic:equals some_condition>
      <script>
           var e = document.getElementById("element");

           e.onClick = my_function();

      </script>
 </logic>
```

But I cant get it working. 
Is there any special syntax?

I've tried with

```
 e.onClick = my_function;
 e.onClick = function(){my_function();}
```

Sadly i'm in IE 6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that some server-side or client-side (thus JavaScript) logic do determinate if you want to set the handler?

Comment: Its server side, the "some_condition" involves a value in request. What I want to do is to assign different handlers according to that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should give `<script>` a `type` attribute:
2. The method to get the reference to an element by id is called `getElementById`
3. `onclick` (as all of JavaScript) is case-sensitive:
4. You assign a reference of a function to event handlers, thus you leave the parenthesis away other wise it will call the function then and there.

.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var e = document.getElementById("element");
  e.onclick = my_function;
</script>
```

**EDIT:**
If the logic is server-side its probaly easier to set then event handler in the HTML code then:

```
<a href="" <% if (some_condition) print "onload='my_function();'" %>>
```

(That is pseudo code, depending on you server-side language)

Comment: Thanks, I actually meant getElementById, but made a typo.

Answer (score -1):

`onclick` is case sensitive

Comment: Is this a comment, an answer?

Comment: Nah, this is definitely a comment. xD

Comment: It's an answer. The original code doesn't work because it is  assigning the function to `onClick`, which isn't an event that ever fires. You have to assign it to `onclick`. (There might be other issues, but that is an obvious cause of brokenness)

Comment: Funny thing, the rest of the html page is filled with working `onClick`s. Did some googling and some examples appear with lower case c, some with uppercase. Is this an IE6 'feature' ?

Comment: *boggle* must be a Microsoft thing. I've never seen it work (possibly it only works in quirks mode)